# How to disable ssl_request log on Apache?

Tags: windows, apache-2.4, logging, apache2

Our internal Apache instance on a Windows server is regularly filling up the disk with `C:\Apache24\logs\ssl_request.log.yyyy-MM-dd.log` logs.

They seem to be rotated, although their sizes vary (200 - 700MB).

I see no value in these logs for this internal server. Can I disable them?

I found no entry in the `httpd.conf` - only for the error and access logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might need to check the extra/*.conf files (most likely `httpd-ssl.conf`).
I'd suggest you just ripgrep your way through your C:\Apache24\conf and search for `CustomLog`

Comment: Config is found in `conf\extra\httpd-ahssl.conf` and `conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf`. Not sure which one is right. The one in ssl has no logrotate configured, and the one in ahssl has 100M logrotate which doesn't match the files either.

Comment: OK: Found it: httpd-ahssl.conf is referenced in httpd.conf and seems to be the active one.